# how to enable dom.allow_script_to_close_windows on firefox 14+ with java script when browser is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, window

I'm trying to get a solution in order to close automatically firefox window setting a timeout, now I already have a solution but is not working on firefox 14+ and I don't know how to fix that:| I read a lot and I found a forum where someone say that is the "dom.allow_script_to_close_windows" is set on true you can close window automatically even in firefox. My question is how to set this option on true? using a native java script.
Thank you :)

Comment: Do you mean overriding the browser setting from a web site?

Comment: Well, I hope it isn't possible given that it's a security feature :)

Comment: :| at least another solution for closing firefox browser using a javascrip :|

Comment: A Firefox add-on. What's your precise use case?

Comment: I need to set a timer on a webpage to be automatically closed because I have an app that use many web pages in same time and few of them I want to close after few seconds.